# Second type item appears when scrolling in android, different items listview example

Tags: android, listview, scroll, position, items

I want to add new `imageview` item for `7th, 14th, 21th` positions.

When I add new item and create new layout type for it , it didn't work well.

When scrolling lots of `imageview` (type2) items appear in different positions.

**How can i solve this and whree is my mistake?**

(I tried only for seventh position in this codes to solve scrolling problem. )

```
    public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    MyFragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    List<Tier3Category>list;   
    Context context;    
    ListView myList;
    OneriDetail myObj;
    Tier3Category obj;


    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Tier3Category> list, MyFragmentManager mFragmentManager,
             ListView myList, int type) {
        super();
        this.mFragmentManager = mFragmentManager;
        this.list = list;
    if(list.size()>1)
        list.add(7,new Tier3Category("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", false, false, false, "", "", "", ""));
        Log.w("", list.size()+"asd");
        this.context = context;
        this.myList = myList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Tier3Category getItem(int position) {
        if (getCount()>0){
            return list.get(position);
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }   
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         final ViewHolder1 vh ;
         final ViewHolder2 vh2;   


         if(position!=7){           
         try {
            if (convertView==null){          
                 vh = new ViewHolder1();

                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                            R.layout.adapter_oneri_list, parent, false);
                    vh.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_title);            
                    convertView.setTag(vh);
             }                                      
            else{
                vh = (ViewHolder1)convertView.getTag();
                }   
             convertView.setTag(vh);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            }        
         }

         else {
             try {
                if (convertView==null){     
                 vh2 = new ViewHolder2();
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_adv_item, parent,false);
                    vh2.adv_photo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.adv_image);
                    convertView.setTag(vh2);    

                 }                                      
                    else{
                        vh2 = (ViewHolder2)convertView.getTag();
                        }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               
         }

         return convertView;
    }
    public  class ViewHolder1{
        TextView comment_count , like_count , follow_count , username , time , title , content, location , categoryname;
        RoundedImageView sugg_photo;
        RoundedImageView user_photo;
        RelativeLayout threedot;
        ImageView likeIcon , commentIcon , followIcon;
    }

    public class ViewHolder2{
        ImageView adv_photo;        
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason you're having problems is that you haven't realized that the ListView is recycling it's views. It seems you are using 2 different viewholders depending on whether the view is at position 7 or not - therefore you are essentially using 2 different types of views. The problem is that ListView doesn't know that, so a view you created at, say, position 5 might end up in position 7 after scrolling. This is passed in as the convertView argument.

I am willing to bet that you're getting a lot of stack traces printed in LogCat - a very important detail.

The simplest way around it would be to check what kind of view you're getting as convertView:

```
     if(position!=7){           
     try {
        if (convertView==null || convertView.getTag() ! instanceof ViewHolder1){
```

and

```
    else {
         try {
            if (convertView==null || convertView.getTag() ! instanceof ViewHolder2){
```

Another thing I suggest you do is stop checking for position 7, but instead do:

```
if (position % 7 != 0)
```

This will check whether position is a multiple of 7 - covering all of the cases you mentioned.